# Unable to compile vim with python3 support on a Windows machine

Tags: vim, python-3.5

I've compiled the latest `vim` using `MinGW-w64` with dynamic `Python2` and dynamic `Python3` support. Here is what I get when I run `:version`:

```
+python/dyn
+python3/dyn
```

However for some reason I don't have `python3` support. Here is how I check it:

`echo has('python')` produces `1`
`echo has('python3')` produces `0`

What could be the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: The `python3.dll` (or so) probably cannot be loaded. This is the `/dyn` part: The actual language interpreter is dynamically loaded on first use. Check your PATH and Python installations.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Are you sure that `python3` should be in the `PATH`? I don't have `python2` in my `PATH` and it works. As far as I understand one doesn't need to have `python x` in the `PATH` as long as corrects paths to executables and to the libraries are specified.

Comment: Yes, either PATH or the correct path has been compiled in. The `:version` output might tell you the latter.